# Javascript uncheck all checkboxes with <input type="checkbox" name="QuoteRequiredServices[]" syntax

Tags: javascript

```
<label class="checkbox inline">
<input type="checkbox" name="Services[]" value="service1"> Service 1
</label>
<label class="checkbox inline">
<input type="checkbox" name="Services[]" value="service2"> Service 2
</label>
```

I am using Services[] so that $_POST['Services'] is mapped to an array in PHP, containing the values required.

However, on the client side I also need to uncheck all these checkboxes after the form has been submitted (to PHP). Fairly simple Javascript: (actual checkbox group is 8 long).

```
for (j=0; j<8; j++){
fields[6][j].checked=false;
}
```

where:

```
fields[6] = formob.Services[];
formob=document.forms["FooterQuote"];
```

The problem is that I cannot put Services[] into a Javascript array. I have tried using the following methods: (pseudo-code, only syntax matters here)

```
var fields=[formob.text1, formob.text2, formob.text3, formob.Services[]];
//Syntax error at Services[]

var fields=new Array(formob.text1, formob.text2, formob.text3, formob.Services[]);
//Syntax error at Services[]

var fields=new Array(formob.text1, formob.text2, formob.text3);
fields.push(formob.Services[]);
//Syntax error at Services[]
```

So, unfortunately I can't push Services[] into a Javascript array, as far as I can tell.

I have also tried using formob.Services instead, and this doesn't work either.

Has anybody got any ideas how I can make the name="Services[]" syntax for checkboxes work in a Javascript array, so I can cycle through and uncheck them all? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to address to checkboxes like this:

```
var services = ​document.forms['FooterQuote']['Services​[]']​;
```

Have a look at this article for details: [Dot and Square Bracket Notations](http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/js-dot-notation/).

So to uncheck it use:

```
for (var i = 0; i < services.length; i++) {
    services[i].checked = false;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much! That worked perfectly. To confirm, you can also push that value into an array and loop it. Perfect answer. :)

Comment: This doens't take into account the single-checkbox case which Services isn't an array. Actually, most of the answer on Internet don't take care this case.

Answer (score 1):

This is when you should use [square bracket notation](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html).

You can do

```
formob["Services[]"]
```

or

```
formob.elements["Services[]"]
```

Comment: Thankyou very much,  awesome answer too. Accepted the answerer who got in just before you, but yep this method worked perfectly. Thankyou! :)