# On navigating back,checkbox not getting unchecked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

i have following code in which i m appending checkboxe values with hash in url,but when i navigate back from there,checkboxes are not getting unchecked .please check the code below

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"> I have a car<br>

<script>
$checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox');
$checkboxes.change(function(){
    window.location.hash = 'check=' + $checkboxes.filter(':checked').map(function(){
        return this.value;   
    }).get().join(",");
    console.log(window.location.hash);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

what should i change in url to make checkboxes unchecked after navigating back...

Comment: Have you run the your code through 'tidy'?  Just to help, a <input> tag must be either paired with a </input> tag or self closed with ' />' at the end of the tag contents.  Another detail, <br> requires a closing </br> or (better written as) <br />.  the input tag does not have a text component, so use a label tag.  Unfortunately, most browsers make guesses as to what is wanted rather than adhering to the html rules.

Comment: both the input type=checkbox, have the same name="vehicle".  These are not radio buttons, so all names should be unique unless the names are an array.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is

```
$(window).on("hashchange", function() {
    // code here
}
```

However it might be tricky to write code that doesn't clear checkboxes on every hash change.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code like below:

```
$checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
```

Comment: make the change only in that line... reamining code will be same

Answer (score 0):

```
Note: This is taken from another answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466648/

<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Vehicles[]" value="Bike"> I have a bike
</label>
<br />
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Vehicles[]" value="Car"> I have a car
</label>
<br /> 

So if your form definition has the attribute: name="myform"
then you can do the following in javascript to uncheck the checkboxes:

var services = ​document.forms['myform']['Vehicles​[]']​;

for (var i = 0; i < Vehicles.length; i++) 
{
    Vehicles[i].checked = false;
}
```